# Прошу комментарий к Await / Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем примет. Прошу совета, верно ли делаю относительно своих комментариев. И возможные **исправления** в по части последовательности выполнения кода.

```
{
    var history = await _historyService.GetHistory(_id); // ---- Долгая, но данные нужны уже тут, потому просто жду.
    var resultTask = _httpService.RunWithHistoryAsync(history, (int)_id); //---- Долгая, Выполняю в фоне.
    SendStopButton(_id);
    SetActivity(_id);
    var historyTask = _historyService.GetHistory(_id); - история изменилась, но данные нужны позже, выполняю в фоне.
    
    while (!resultTask.IsCompleted) //---- Нужно, иначе перестает показывать прелоад ( что юзер пишет в чат). Он настроен на 3сек, код выплоняеться дольше.
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        SetActivity(_id); //---- сам прелоад
    }
    var result = await resultTask; //---- не жду в методе  SendMessage, тк необходимо максимально сократить время между удалением и новым сообщением. Иначе может выйти так, что historyTask готов и удаление сработает, а result еще не готов и между этими методами пройдет вечность.
    MessageDelite(_id, await historyTask); //---- Удаляю последнее сообщение
    SendMessage(_id, result); //---- максимально быстро отправляю после удаления
     
    return;
};
```

1. например `Task<List<MessageInfo>> historyTask = Task.Run(() => _historyService.GetHistory(_id));` и потом ожидание, равносильно `var historyTask = _historyService.GetHistory(_id);` и потом ожидание
2. Что-то можно улучшить? Я понимаю, что код короткий, но не уверен что делаю лучшим образом эту часть, тк учусь. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет смысла в `Task.Run`, если вы работаете с асинхронной операцией.

Можно например вынести поллинг в отдельный метод и останавливать его токеном отмены.

```
private async Task HeartbeatAsync(int id, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SetActivity(id);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { }
}
```

Тогда получится вот так

```
using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
Task preload = HeartbeatAsync(_id, cts.Token);
try
{
    var history = await _historyService.GetHistory(_id);
    var resultTask = _httpService.RunWithHistoryAsync(history, (int)_id);
    SendStopButton(_id);
    var historyResult = await _historyService.GetHistory(_id);
    var result = await resultTask;
    MessageDelite(_id, historyResult); // не Delite, в Delete пишется
    SendMessage(_id, result);
}
finally
{
    cts.Cancel();
}
await preload;
```

Возможно еще что-то можно оптимизировать, возможно от цикла можно избавиться, но вы не показали что из себя представляют вызываемые методы и какими типами данных они оперируют, особенно `SetActivity` (при чем тут 3 секунды и т.д.).

Comment: Метод SetActivity в VKAPI используется для показа точек "O-O-O" в чате, чтобы собеседник знал, что мой бот не завис. (Он активен около 3сек). В целом 1. Я беру историю usera из ВК, 2. отправляю сообщение"⏳Loading..."(что бы иметь возм. отправить кнопку "прервать запрос", она обрывает post у httpclient через токен). 3. Отправляю вопрос на генерацию ответа. 4.Кручу лоадер. 5. Когда ответ готов удаляю сообщение с "⏳Loading..." у обоих пользователей, и 5. Отправляю сгенерированный ответ в чат. Такие дела) Спасибо Вам за вариант с токеном отмены

Comment: @ПавелВайт галочка всё там же. Кстати, если там 3-секундный запас, то поллинг можно сделать реже, например не 2 раза в секунду, а раз в 2 секунды.

Comment: Может получится так, что ответ для отправки вот-вот уже готов, скажем через 0.1с. И прямо перед носом срабатывает поллинг еще на 2 сек. А он в свою очередь в моем примере в while блокирует отправку сообщения. В отличие от Вашего)). Такие задержки критичны. Потому ставил 0.5 .

Comment: @ПавелВайт Ничего он не блокирует, он асинхронный. И токен отмены останавливает это ожидание моментально. Вызываете Cancel и оно прерывается сразу же. Ставьте 2 секунды, нормально будет работать. И меньше нагрузка на сеть и сервер.